# How do I add a video if PayPal IPN Returns Verified

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to use PayPal IPN for the first time but I'm struggling to make it work end to end. If the IPN response is validated, the thank you page should show a video. If it isn't validated (eg. if somebody tries going directly to the thank you page, rather than through a successful PayPal transaction), it should show an error message.

I've managed to return a "Sent" status in my IPN history when checking in PayPal, but my thank you page (which contains the IPN validator) presents an error 500. The error log suggests no post data is being sent to the page, even though PayPal is registering it was a success.

```
<?php namespace Listener;

require('PaypalIPN.php');

use PaypalIPN;

$ipn = new PaypalIPN();

$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {

    echo ("My video will go here");
}

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 

?>
```

PaypalIPN.php looks like this:

```
<?php

class PaypalIPN
{
/** @var bool Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used. */
private $use_sandbox = false;
/** @var bool Indicates if the local certificates are used. */
private $use_local_certs = true;

/** Production Postback URL */
const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
/** Sandbox Postback URL */
const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

/** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
/** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
const INVALID = 'INVALID';

/**
 * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
 * should not be enabled in production).
 * @return void
 */
public function useSandbox()
{
    $this->use_sandbox = true;
}

/**
 * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
 * environments).
 * @return void
 */
public function usePHPCerts()
{
    $this->use_local_certs = false;
}

/**
 * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPaypalUri()
{
    if ($this->use_sandbox) {
        return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
    } else {
        return self::VERIFY_URI;
    }
}

/**
 * Verification Function
 * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
 *
 * @return bool
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function verifyIPN()
{
    if ( ! count($_POST)) {
        throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
    }

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2) {
            // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
            if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                    $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                }
            }
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
    }

    // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
    $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
    if ($this->use_local_certs) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
        'Connection: Close',
    ));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ( ! ($res)) {
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $errstr = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
    }

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $http_code = $info['http_code'];
    if ($http_code != 200) {
        throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
    if ($res == self::VALID) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to debug your PayPal IPN end-point using cURL or Postman.
IF you're getting "Missing POST Data" it means PayPal is unable to send a notification to your server, make sure your domain is reachable by PayPal - you can do that using IPN Emulator in PayPal's dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing misunderstands the way IPN works.

IPN is a direct post from PayPal to your server, and does not, cannot, and should not directly involve the client's web browser or thank you page in any way.

Your IPN listener should update your database to mark an order as paid.

Your thank you page can read from the database.

These are asynchronous operations.

---

For a more robust solution, forget about using IPN and instead integrate a front-end checkout UI like https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , which will call 2 routes on your server (which you must create) to 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', each of which will communicate with the PayPal API as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/